# 15 day funds hold on Coinbase

Tags: coinbase.com, copay

I've linked my Copay wallet to my Coinbase account. I wasn't aware of the 15 day hold from my bank account on the funds I purchased.

Has anyone had that happen before? If so, did it take the full 15 days or did it clear sooner than that?

Also, my Coinbase account shows that my Copay account is connected to it when I'm logged in on a computer but not the app. And the Copay app doesn't show my Coinbase account is connected to it. I've completed the authorization process and I still don't see my Coinbase on my Copay app.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to call coinbase support. They will point you in the right direction, usually its dramatic time saver :) Happened with me before that they would clear/release funds right away for some cases (unfortunately had a bunch within the last year). Their support staff is very responsive, doing its best since the platform has problems with scaling and code quality.